# SeLU Activation Function x-Parameter causes a typeError

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, activation-function

I am building a CNN and am defining a fully connected layer with SeLU as its activation and AlphaDropout(0.5). I am trying to initialize SeLU with a `tf.random.normal` distribution as follows:

```
dist = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([5, 5, 1, 32], stddev=np.sqrt(1/25)))
```

Here is the code for my fully connected layer:

```
def FullyConnectedLayer(denseUnits, seluDistribution, batchMomentum, alphaDropRate):
    model.add(Dense(denseUnits, activity_regularizer='l2'))
    model.add(Activation(selu(x=seluDistribution)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=batchMomentum, epsilon=0.001))
    model.add(AlphaDropout(alphaDropRate, noise_shape=None, seed=None))
    return model
```

```
model = FullyConnectedLayer(512, dist, 0.99, 0.5) # 4 LAYERS
```

I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-f0000c6b1512> in <module>
     11 model = ConvAvgStack                  (256, (3, 3), (1, 1), 1, 0.99, 0.3, None, (2, 2), (2, 2)) # 5 LAYERS
     12 model = FlattenLayer                  (                                                       ) # 1 LAYER
---> 13 model = FullyConnectedLayer           (512,   dist,            0.99, 0.5                      ) # 4 LAYERS
     14 model = FullyConnectedLayer           (512,   dist,            0.99, 0.5                      ) # 4 LAYERS
     15 model = OutputLayer                   ( 28                                                    ) # 2 LAYERS

<ipython-input-119-58375bdf8845> in FullyConnectedLayer(denseUnits, seluDistribution, batchMomentum, alphaDropRate)
     56 def FullyConnectedLayer(denseUnits, seluDistribution, batchMomentum, alphaDropRate):
     57     model.add(Dense(denseUnits, activity_regularizer='l2'))
---> 58     model.add(Activation(gelu(x=seluDistribution)))
     59     model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=batchMomentum, epsilon=0.001))
     60     model.add(AlphaDropout(alphaDropRate, noise_shape=None, seed=None))

~\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\layers\core.py in __init__(self, activation, **kwargs)
    376     super(Activation, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    377     self.supports_masking = True
--> 378     self.activation = activations.get(activation)
    379 
    380   def call(self, inputs):

~\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\activations.py in get(identifier)
    452     raise TypeError(
    453         'Could not interpret activation function identifier: {}'.format(
--> 454             repr(identifier)))

TypeError: Could not interpret activation function identifier: <tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 5, 1, 32), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[-1.26586094e-01, -1.02963023e-01,  3.14652212e-02,
           5.46985120e-02,  8.40277504e-03,  8.54115710e-02,
          -1.39087364e-01,  1.13992631e-01,  1.52557418e-01,
          -1.09972686e-01, -5.12595251e-02, -1.58538278e-02,
           3.14276330e-02, -3.38738156e-03, -1.00402050e-02,
           9.30291191e-02,  3.55263725e-02, -1.13361394e-02,
          -1.29528284e-01,  1.63152684e-02,  1.01518132e-01,
          -4.35875840e-02,  1.46785110e-01, -2.23108958e-02,
          -2.09968127e-02, -8.54036435e-02,  9.01642349e-03,
           8.55906028e-03,  1.10763777e-02,  1.35530531e-01,
          -4.25574742e-02,  4.80710454e-02]],

        [[ 9.34263412e-03,  1.06001608e-01, -7.65870064e-02,
           2.61795402e-01, -7.57196844e-02, -1.04116738e-01,
          -8.02185014e-02,  6.67698979e-02, -8.98385793e-02,
           7.15453252e-02, -9.78381783e-02,  4.91873287e-02,
           1.30732795e-02,  1.55197978e-01, -3.54499035e-02,
           7.09592476e-02,  4.96367812e-02,  3.68002579e-02,
           1.16795145e-01, -1.42192841e-01,  4.91914898e-02,
           4.16900441e-02,  3.53892595e-01,  1.78602412e-01,
          -6.12295903e-02,  7.36039877e-02, -1.33156419e-01,
           2.31991991e-01,  8.40820521e-02, -4.55706231e-02,
           2.51267888e-02,  2.58378834e-01]],

        [[-1.38585389e-01,  1.03538044e-01,  1.76681668e-01,
          -6.94317510e-03,  6.14152141e-02, -3.92788239e-02,
           2.71100029e-02, -7.32106417e-02,  1.82974041e-01,
          -5.83523549e-02,  6.68111816e-02,  5.49897328e-02,
          -5.77139147e-02, -7.64194950e-02, -7.55715296e-02,
          -4.95074578e-02,  7.71198049e-02,  5.40203564e-02,
           1.55790344e-01, -4.58407030e-02, -3.59891504e-02,
          -9.74030495e-02, -1.00650810e-01,  1.23783059e-01,
          -8.46874043e-02, -1.04908131e-01, -2.63819955e-02,
           1.40812725e-01, -2.82377452e-02, -2.38265842e-02,
          -1.31487399e-01,  1.30674899e-01]],

        [[ 6.60606772e-02,  1.46065757e-01,  1.59279909e-02,
           8.10257494e-02, -7.72565231e-02, -9.53363404e-02,
          -1.20391339e-01, -7.02986643e-02, -2.74278801e-02,
          -1.29030854e-01, -7.62277395e-02, -1.19075023e-01,
           6.59862757e-02, -7.62806982e-02,  1.67345591e-02,
           1.51549906e-01, -1.10640965e-01, -1.34767130e-01,
           2.70601243e-01, -9.72772986e-02,  2.07788169e-01,
           6.56675100e-02, -2.64023039e-02,  1.13911137e-01,
          -9.22646299e-02,  7.98776373e-02,  6.54103830e-02,
          -6.72401339e-02, -4.81364317e-02, -6.03620708e-02,
          -2.84200851e-02, -9.10447016e-02]],

        [[-1.23140588e-01,  1.10491589e-01, -9.61843282e-02,
          -8.91052186e-02,  4.01075035e-01,  1.94666237e-02,
           1.95948835e-02, -1.25196623e-02, -9.97422487e-02,
          -2.61222124e-02, -1.56512097e-01,  9.74281505e-02,
          -3.66279632e-02,  6.65708026e-03,  9.61058680e-03,
          -1.21156186e-01, -2.98077669e-02,  1.66137442e-02,
           1.17182136e-01, -1.13791995e-01, -1.27656450e-02,
           1.41541764e-01,  6.68982640e-02,  4.79037128e-02,
          -3.38280275e-02, -9.28360224e-02, -7.76154548e-02,
          -7.96113610e-02, -2.57881228e-02, -1.58247918e-01,
           1.13235332e-01,  1.41958997e-01]]],


       [[[-1.13160208e-01, -1.98329911e-02,  1.20878376e-01,
          -1.13716172e-02, -5.21509871e-02,  7.25255907e-02,
          -1.12730011e-01, -7.29970336e-02,  6.37045652e-02,
           7.17113987e-02, -4.47467379e-02,  5.34803495e-02,
          -8.64603445e-02, -2.22087242e-02, -2.47925967e-02,
           8.34110975e-02,  7.71386176e-02, -4.75004427e-02,
          -6.44451613e-03, -1.73095725e-02, -6.07393086e-02,
           5.75710386e-02, -5.33160344e-02, -8.67358595e-02,
          -4.96991165e-02, -3.15147117e-02,  2.43039820e-02,
           1.42646387e-01,  1.22333430e-01, -3.74684632e-02,
          -7.35211000e-02, -6.92363605e-02]],

        [[ 3.96580771e-02,  1.26118317e-01,  1.16271339e-01,
           1.54558346e-01,  1.14904214e-02, -2.90639680e-02,
          -5.80145419e-02, -2.15136074e-03, -9.12490934e-02,
           1.45193376e-02, -3.00550666e-02,  1.45778894e-01,
           4.00692225e-02, -1.92456692e-02,  6.31886274e-02,
          -1.27457187e-01,  3.60154063e-02,  9.91806835e-02,
           8.99021700e-02,  2.88172178e-02, -1.59403589e-02,
           4.76611021e-04, -3.30352560e-02,  1.15945041e-02,
          -4.64559309e-02, -2.11531147e-02,  4.10205543e-01,
          -4.43787202e-02,  4.39099297e-02,  3.06370091e-02,
          -9.87873599e-02, -5.10304309e-02]],

        [[ 2.13202462e-02,  1.41525701e-01, -4.84775938e-02,
           2.97882885e-01,  2.19049938e-02,  3.68789248e-02,
           2.60351785e-02, -9.37016606e-02,  5.48276715e-02,
          -1.43082231e-01,  4.21900637e-02, -1.17563821e-01,
          -3.71489525e-02, -1.45584494e-01, -1.12884097e-01,
          -7.87854716e-02, -2.01713406e-02, -3.49416770e-02,
          -6.53499886e-02, -2.09143162e-02,  2.94101406e-02,
           4.72677462e-02,  2.33202621e-01, -1.95219535e-02,
           1.19159967e-02, -1.00374170e-01, -8.75894353e-02,
          -5.27165644e-02,  1.19348057e-02, -4.39126566e-02,
          -6.26288429e-02,  4.20925207e-02]],

        [[-8.23830441e-02,  2.23106906e-01,  8.56178179e-02,
           1.73401862e-01, -8.12073424e-02,  2.73483209e-02,
          -5.99831380e-02, -1.71386788e-03, -3.62357125e-02,
          -1.59021363e-01, -2.17766548e-03,  2.16864720e-01,
          -5.73305860e-02, -1.80698894e-02,  1.36940643e-01,
          -1.97473206e-02,  8.14313069e-02,  1.96376622e-01,
           1.41641393e-01,  1.47828847e-01, -8.56224895e-02,
           1.83912277e-01, -1.33015722e-01,  3.97381186e-02,
           1.18237391e-01, -9.23948511e-02,  8.74724891e-03,
           4.36485223e-02,  6.96098059e-02, -4.20766175e-02,
          -6.43103570e-02, -3.85615453e-02]],

        [[-3.53560485e-02,  4.35038935e-03, -7.06349090e-02,
          -2.80691660e-03, -6.92954510e-02,  1.11481667e-01,
           8.37303791e-03,  6.81344569e-02, -7.26705194e-02,
          -4.58219610e-02, -2.38394644e-02, -7.87800774e-02,
           1.69382155e-01,  1.03942029e-01, -1.96680743e-02,
          -1.67009607e-02,  6.01479635e-02,  1.56740978e-01,
          -9.78638828e-02, -4.29860055e-02,  1.38192121e-02,
          -1.36006713e-01, -1.05418041e-01, -2.51792613e-02,
          -1.22639257e-02, -1.21888302e-01, -5.46660051e-02,
          -7.12147309e-03, -6.58531636e-02, -7.14808479e-02,
           9.00977999e-02,  6.35402352e-02]]],


       [[[ 6.32937178e-02,  2.72242278e-01, -3.74731459e-02,
           2.15447005e-02, -1.08312249e-01,  2.10458219e-01,
           3.16671804e-02, -4.71992679e-02,  3.75940092e-02,
          -2.62564681e-02, -1.54855132e-01,  7.81283434e-03,
           5.74255362e-02,  1.75963491e-02, -4.40403447e-02,
          -8.01301673e-02,  7.47360140e-02, -5.00108190e-02,
          -7.64894933e-02,  8.45131949e-02, -3.27355303e-02,
          -3.79370786e-02, -6.93783676e-03, -4.87477183e-02,
           9.93528962e-02, -1.05679579e-01, -1.12576345e-02,
           4.84773107e-02, -1.20892882e-01,  7.03079775e-02,
           5.60718998e-02, -1.91565454e-02]],

        [[-7.98909813e-02,  2.59152979e-01,  1.75541520e-01,
           3.17000411e-02, -1.23978313e-02,  5.59741072e-02,
          -8.12215135e-02, -9.54297185e-02,  1.99518725e-03,
          -3.72358635e-02, -1.39946237e-01, -5.76626435e-02,
          -7.13582858e-02,  5.86171262e-02, -1.39267772e-01,
           5.99225797e-02, -2.99881045e-02,  7.08236769e-02,
          -1.00216493e-01,  2.68728107e-01,  1.63495377e-01,
           2.52694320e-02, -7.93625191e-02, -3.71078290e-02,
          -2.24205833e-02,  1.44553408e-01, -9.67240557e-02,
           7.93731958e-02,  1.79968283e-01, -8.94036815e-02,
          -1.24277532e-01, -1.40620157e-01]],

        [[-5.69531657e-02,  1.71630532e-01,  2.86230773e-01,
          -5.93378842e-02, -1.71954520e-02, -3.26295868e-02,
           1.84255466e-01,  1.47821277e-01, -2.54929177e-02,
          -3.98173966e-02,  7.21049905e-02, -6.91456124e-02,
          -1.23138815e-01,  1.33402884e-01, -1.02245316e-01,
           2.63660389e-04,  4.64727916e-02,  5.91520481e-02,
          -4.69203852e-02, -1.75676849e-02,  1.40360445e-01,
           1.67195871e-02, -1.11560198e-02,  4.65030931e-02,
           1.73744947e-01, -1.47689149e-01,  1.10403180e-01,
          -3.40559036e-02,  3.35928686e-02, -1.04908220e-01,
           3.52294981e-01, -1.09612457e-01]],

        [[-7.85556585e-02, -1.18466914e-01,  1.53003752e-01,
           3.53524536e-01,  8.51708353e-02,  1.50212459e-02,
           6.00347035e-02,  6.17506169e-02,  3.86744961e-02,
          -4.67218924e-03, -1.16112582e-01,  5.51390201e-02,
          -1.52055770e-02,  3.54320277e-03,  3.42624858e-02,
           1.12283051e-01,  9.55326110e-02,  1.21229617e-02,
           2.53406595e-02, -8.03915039e-03, -5.12704402e-02,
          -1.05386212e-01,  1.98949352e-02,  2.73315758e-02,
          -7.58572146e-02,  1.03625186e-01,  2.05493998e-03,
           2.16567993e-01, -1.08607717e-01, -1.77554917e-02,
          -1.01805991e-02,  2.19766423e-02]],

        [[-1.00509115e-02,  2.22494956e-02, -9.08879191e-02,
           1.40368611e-01, -7.76991919e-02,  4.06601280e-02,
          -8.11229870e-02,  9.98405516e-02, -5.72074987e-02,
          -1.33951874e-02,  3.92576605e-02,  1.16789080e-01,
          -1.89318452e-02, -1.59033425e-02,  9.48152542e-02,
          -2.66773477e-02,  1.37753570e-02,  1.79445334e-02,
          -6.62883669e-02, -9.37851295e-02,  1.94142580e-01,
           1.51747808e-01,  1.18895158e-01, -9.38543454e-02,
          -1.28269400e-02,  1.25869989e-01,  1.50878415e-01,
          -2.11219154e-02, -1.05045862e-01, -2.73662023e-02,
           1.34711221e-01, -3.39821167e-02]]],


       [[[ 1.83003962e-01, -4.02955636e-02,  7.92874582e-03,
          -1.04859909e-02,  1.41754048e-02, -1.52763631e-02,
          -9.11424682e-02,  3.24082047e-01,  1.05546042e-02,
           1.61272004e-01, -6.35793507e-02,  3.40929255e-02,
           1.42173097e-01,  2.29736529e-02, -9.50964168e-02,
           4.37728036e-03,  2.28861179e-02, -9.05632600e-02,
           4.51861843e-02,  1.37779471e-02, -1.46172449e-01,
           1.64313123e-01, -3.22954543e-02, -5.28477319e-02,
           4.69896160e-02, -1.41132519e-01, -7.68374726e-02,
          -1.30687788e-01, -3.98224816e-02,  1.38061410e-02,
           1.22488514e-01,  1.80401299e-02]],

        [[ 2.33758405e-01, -9.26907063e-02,  1.65917858e-01,
           6.44484162e-02, -2.50724498e-02,  6.55293986e-02,
           8.01478773e-02, -1.14124026e-02,  1.28012270e-01,
           2.19843611e-01,  6.57515675e-02, -3.07754893e-02,
           5.73609546e-02,  2.30572656e-01, -3.31373070e-03,
          -1.22203723e-01, -2.83196904e-02,  1.02213569e-01,
           1.01013631e-01, -1.12923756e-01,  6.65007606e-02,
           3.05338297e-02, -3.15904021e-02,  2.79964060e-02,
          -5.63387433e-03, -3.08787469e-02,  1.96257643e-02,
          -7.37890229e-02, -1.93086471e-02,  1.30984381e-01,
           1.62610561e-01, -1.23884566e-01]],

        [[-5.09779751e-02,  6.08728305e-02, -8.07061568e-02,
           1.61063105e-01, -1.54089145e-02, -3.93352509e-02,
           1.43149942e-01, -2.58404091e-02, -2.68822517e-02,
          -1.26804784e-01, -1.43676013e-01, -3.28507088e-02,
           7.94891044e-02, -1.40485764e-01, -8.11149403e-02,
           6.17359020e-02,  2.30427265e-01, -1.29583761e-01,
           9.54858139e-02, -3.21873813e-03, -1.57925244e-02,
           9.96306986e-02, -1.02927998e-01,  8.71243626e-02,
          -1.66144117e-03, -7.41888210e-03,  1.42028257e-01,
          -4.99214791e-02, -1.86899900e-02, -1.09298825e-02,
          -8.03249031e-02, -1.00237548e-01]],

        [[-7.80191123e-02,  4.05082256e-02,  7.47731477e-02,
          -8.76973122e-02, -2.91744564e-02,  1.23694569e-01,
           2.35005572e-01, -1.05778649e-01, -4.78913225e-02,
          -1.49070352e-01,  2.42730626e-03,  3.52480598e-02,
           9.97696498e-06, -1.27278671e-01, -1.08177230e-01,
          -5.62792830e-03, -2.28355639e-02, -1.27415329e-01,
           3.05411909e-02,  1.00286447e-01,  1.83264986e-02,
          -8.48858505e-02, -3.52028869e-02, -7.95315206e-02,
          -3.92727107e-02, -4.16678861e-02,  2.39140958e-01,
           4.07571718e-02, -9.46874619e-02,  1.50908276e-01,
          -1.44019471e-02, -8.69576260e-03]],

        [[-1.67441964e-02, -1.43177100e-02, -9.23768803e-02,
           4.70091105e-02,  4.42117406e-03,  6.48477301e-02,
          -2.72830930e-02,  7.51334131e-02, -2.28366554e-02,
           9.48273912e-02,  4.46406417e-02,  6.07026815e-02,
           5.69610856e-02, -4.77909558e-02, -6.64769933e-02,
          -5.57800010e-02, -1.31770581e-01,  9.31192283e-03,
          -1.38517320e-02, -1.41043484e-01, -6.42404705e-02,
           2.63120145e-01,  1.80331752e-01, -1.43979434e-02,
          -4.86476049e-02, -1.12639852e-01,  7.89660513e-02,
           1.24138966e-01,  5.12700714e-02, -1.20767031e-03,
          -1.09081008e-01, -3.03610712e-02]]],


       [[[-1.40361011e-01,  1.21919084e-02,  4.36685272e-02,
          -3.61564793e-02, -1.11773185e-01,  2.25092173e-02,
          -1.02469876e-01,  1.76996499e-01,  4.30173017e-02,
          -2.26258971e-02,  2.11037025e-01,  9.66922417e-02,
           5.76661676e-02,  9.65369982e-04, -1.35565817e-01,
          -4.83587980e-02,  4.68245940e-04, -1.47096828e-01,
           8.96992441e-03,  4.12831195e-02,  9.53651369e-02,
          -2.91392524e-02,  8.22411999e-02,  2.07852814e-02,
          -4.12134677e-02,  5.33621386e-02,  9.24792588e-02,
           8.16729572e-03,  4.25154343e-02,  6.19177930e-02,
           7.98290670e-02, -8.52704328e-03]],

        [[ 1.66879535e-01,  6.54919222e-02, -3.27483788e-02,
          -1.43241754e-03, -1.14416316e-01, -2.12962832e-02,
          -4.46583293e-02,  2.71647628e-02, -5.61558232e-02,
           1.09621109e-02,  1.67668343e-01,  3.30472551e-02,
           7.05115721e-02,  7.84466881e-03,  1.08160205e-01,
           2.66151220e-01,  1.52581872e-03,  7.19077215e-02,
          -1.24854170e-01,  1.25476092e-01, -7.09585026e-02,
          -4.40548174e-02,  7.21732453e-02,  7.45785460e-02,
           3.44901420e-02,  2.10928824e-02, -7.80880824e-02,
          -1.17296316e-01, -1.46051958e-01,  1.88378561e-02,
           6.55523613e-02,  3.32243517e-02]],

        [[ 2.60874778e-01, -1.45940065e-01, -9.79427770e-02,
          -8.68195742e-02,  2.04389215e-01, -2.24198923e-02,
           4.23102900e-02, -7.01505691e-02, -1.27080590e-01,
           6.70303479e-02,  1.60573255e-02, -7.93380756e-03,
          -8.38927086e-03, -4.99465019e-02,  4.69646640e-02,
          -7.15569034e-02, -1.78242605e-02, -8.51068646e-03,
           4.20920074e-01,  7.50197982e-03, -6.86415285e-02,
           7.11418912e-02,  1.07180420e-03, -9.36960131e-02,
           1.57825544e-01,  5.96512817e-02,  1.75660148e-01,
          -3.08227092e-02, -4.82530929e-02,  8.31630453e-02,
          -4.16018628e-02, -7.55471215e-02]],

        [[ 2.24076852e-01, -1.39667824e-01,  7.93220941e-03,
          -1.78845283e-02, -5.64770252e-02, -7.84719810e-02,
           5.26466146e-02,  6.62457757e-03,  2.76956528e-01,
           9.01412778e-03, -1.48465708e-01, -9.00324360e-02,
          -1.81565285e-02,  1.24106847e-01, -6.28474308e-03,
          -1.72791779e-02, -3.47166769e-02, -4.92920280e-02,
           1.33945951e-02, -1.16457433e-01, -1.28861982e-02,
           1.83324851e-02, -1.37674257e-01, -8.29964876e-02,
          -9.12440866e-02,  6.42236844e-02, -1.16013244e-01,
          -7.96606317e-02,  1.50838092e-01, -4.71229590e-02,
          -4.02066261e-02,  1.17019311e-01]],

        [[-3.95799540e-02, -4.35096361e-02, -9.93420109e-02,
           3.89132760e-02,  8.42780769e-02, -1.38364257e-02,
           2.48586033e-02, -8.65626428e-03,  1.72410719e-02,
          -6.20126911e-02,  1.93700612e-01,  5.02851121e-02,
          -9.00325775e-02,  1.32245719e-01,  2.68575907e-01,
          -8.08344856e-02, -4.56905663e-02,  1.26069590e-01,
           5.42675406e-02,  1.27283424e-01,  2.92954836e-02,
           2.07115993e-01, -1.58712193e-01, -2.03064550e-02,
          -6.64912462e-02,  9.61613879e-02, -1.48803489e-02,
           1.32543296e-01, -1.13899536e-01,  5.34827523e-02,
```

I am unable to initialize the random distribution for the SeLU activation function. All help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to include code that reproduces the problem, this code is incomplete, where is the selu function defined for example?

Comment: Absolutely, I am sorry, I will try to add in some code to reproduce the issue. The selu function is imported from ```tensorflow.python.keras.activations```. But, StackOverflow says I have reached the post length limit...

Comment: I am trying to reproduce something like this: https://towardsdatascience.com/selu-make-fnns-great-again-snn-8d61526802a9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think there may no exist `Activation(selu(x=dist))` such usage. For `selu` use in the `Activation` as a `function` not the output of the `selu`. The implement of the `selu` can be found below:

```py
@keras_export('keras.activations.selu')
def selu(x):
  alpha = 1.6732632423543772848170429916717
  scale = 1.0507009873554804934193349852946
  return scale * K.elu(x, alpha)
```

In your case, I think the [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/selu-make-fnns-great-again-snn-8d61526802a9) means to initialize the weights of the layers rather than `selu`. According to the official api [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations/selu), I think selu can be used as below in your case:

```py
# official usage
model.add(Dense(16, kernel_initializer='lecun_normal', activation='selu')) 

# in your case, for the Dense layer refer to the standard layer in article
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.activations import selu
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, BatchNormalization, AlphaDropout
from tensorflow.keras import initializers

def FullyConnectedLayer(denseUnits, in_dim, batchMomentum, alphaDropRate):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(denseUnits, activity_regularizer='l2', kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=np.sqrt(1/in_dim)), input_shape=(in_dim,)))
    model.add(Activation(selu))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=batchMomentum, epsilon=0.001))
    model.add(AlphaDropout(alphaDropRate, noise_shape=None, seed=None))
    return model

model = FullyConnectedLayer(512, 10, 0.99, 0.5) # 4 LAYERS
```

All in all, happy coding.